# VBA script in Outlook 2016 - Are the data sent to the database encrypted?

Tags: vba, encryption, outlook, transmission

I have a question, my VBA script sends datas to the database, for example `.To`, `.From`, `.Attachment`, etc. Then the VBA script sends an email to recipient. The datas that are sends to the database, is the transmission encrypted ? Or the VBA needs to be specially adapted for encrypted transmission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database? Your Exchange mailbox? Yes, the data sent by Outlook goes over HTTPS.